# How can I get a link to the wishlist page for the WordPress wishlist plugin with code?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am developing a wordpress template and I wanted to know how I can get the address of the wishlist page using a piece of code.
I use a yith wishlist plugin.

I searched all the websites but couldn't find a solution for it

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve the link to the wishlist page in WordPress using the YITH Wishlist plugin, you can use the '**yith_wcwl_get_wishlist_url**' function provided by the plugin. This function retrieves the wishlist page URL. Here's an example of how you can use this function in your WordPress template:

```
<?php
$wishlist_url = yith_wcwl_get_wishlist_url();
echo '<a href="' . esc_url($wishlist_url) . '">Go to Wishlist</a>';
?>
```

This code will generate a link that directs users to the wishlist page of your WordPress website using the YITH Wishlist plugin. Make sure you have the YITH Wishlist plugin activated for this to work.

Comment: I put this function, but we get the error of 'Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function yith_wcwl_get_wishlist_url()'. Please, if you can, introduce me to the correct function.